# Taking all elements from dictionary and append it to string

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary-like below

```
 'results': [{'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.77,
     'transcript': 'everything that you saw it had meaning every hold three more moment of happiness '}],
   'final': True},
  {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.75,
     'transcript': 'none of it matters as you like bleeding out on the battlefield '}],
   'final': True},
  {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.82,
     'transcript': 'none of it changes what is speeding rock does to a body we all '}],
   'final': True},
  {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.8,
     'transcript': 'what does that mean our lives are meaningless '}],
   'final': True},
  {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.9,
     'transcript': 'does that mean that there was no point not being born '}],
   'final': True},
  {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.66,
     'transcript': 'would you say that about slain comrades '}],
   'final': True},
  {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 1.0, 'transcript': 'what about '}],
   'final': True},
  {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.21,
     'transcript': 'I was very meaningless '}],
   'final': True},
  {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.66,
     'transcript': "they were not meeting because we don't know what "}],
   'final': True}]}
```

but I want to append all the elements in the 'transcript' key to a string value. How can I do that in python?

I have tried

```
text = res['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
text
```

But I am only getting the output in the first transcript key, in this case "everything that you saw it had meaning every hold three more moment of happiness". How can I get all of the transcript and append them as a sentence. For example, everything that you saw it had meaning every hold three more moment of happiness.none of it matters as you like bleeding out on the battlefield.....

Comment: Please, check [ask]. And don't post images of code, error, input, output, etc. Post [mre].

Comment: Add the dict as **TEXT** to the question. Explain what you tried (share the code) and the requested output.

Comment: @balderman I have edited the question.

Comment: Based on the data you have posted - what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below combines the requested string into a single string

```
data = {'results': [{'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.77,
                                       'transcript': 'everything that you saw it had meaning every hold three more moment of happiness '}],
                     'final': True},
                    {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.75,
                                       'transcript': 'none of it matters as you like bleeding out on the battlefield '}],
                     'final': True},
                    {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.82,
                                       'transcript': 'none of it changes what is speeding rock does to a body we all '}],
                     'final': True},
                    {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.8,
                                       'transcript': 'what does that mean our lives are meaningless '}],
                     'final': True},
                    {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.9,
                                       'transcript': 'does that mean that there was no point not being born '}],
                     'final': True},
                    {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.66,
                                       'transcript': 'would you say that about slain comrades '}],
                     'final': True},
                    {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 1.0, 'transcript': 'what about '}],
                     'final': True},
                    {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.21,
                                       'transcript': 'I was very meaningless '}],
                     'final': True},
                    {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.66,
                                       'transcript': "they were not meeting because we don't know what "}],
                     'final': True}]}

combined_transcript = ' '.join(x['alternatives'][0]['transcript'] for x in data['results'])
print(combined_transcript)
```

output

```
everything that you saw it had meaning every hold three more moment of happiness  none of it matters as you like bleeding out on the battlefield  none of it changes what is speeding rock does to a body we all  what does that mean our lives are meaningless  does that mean that there was no point not being born  would you say that about slain comrades  what about  I was very meaningless  they were not meeting because we don't know what
```